# How to paste plain text in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, copy-paste, internet-explorer-11, paste, plaintext

Some browsers support pasting of non-formatted text from the clipboard - for instance, Opera Next implements this through the context menu or CTRL+SHIFT+V. However, I need this in IE, which is built-in into Windows 8.1. Is there a way to paste plain text in this browser?

Comment: Where are you copying from and what are you copying into: textbox, textarea, rich textbox? What side-effects are you experiencing?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, there should be no difference if we really paste plain text from the clipboard. At least, in Opera Next CTRL+SHIFT+V works perfectly in all edit boxes regardless of their type.

Comment: As far as I can see, IE doesn't support it. One work-around would be to open Notepad, paste into it, copy it, and paste into IE.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, what I do now :)